# R how to extract the date after using xts package apply.weekly

Tags: r, xts, names

I used the apply.weekly function but can not figure out how to get the actual dates
the output of my object x looks like

```
           [,1]
2012-12-02    2
2012-12-09    9
2012-12-10   10
```

I've tried rownames(x) etc but can't extract out the dates as a vector

Answer (score 1):

`index(x)` #gives you the date required